# pandas date time generation format

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am using the following command to generate date series by the hour

```
pd.date_range(start='01-01-2018', end='01-02-2018', freq='H')
```

It generates dates in the format

```
2018-01-01 00:00:00
2018-01-01 01:00:00
```

However I want in the format

```
2018-01-01T00:00:00
2018-01-01T01:00:00
```

Is there anyway I can generate in this format?
Thanks!

Comment: Tagging the question as `pandas` (instead of simply `python`) would be a good idea (added).

Comment: Your series is in the `datetime` format, you can use [`Series.dt.strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) to make it a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Alex suggested,

```
pd.date_range(start='01-01-2018', end='01-02-2018', freq='H').strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
```

Answer (score 2):

As commented by Alex and Karitkeya, there isn't a way to make it display in the format you want. It's a specific datetime data type that renders in a specific way. If you turn these data into strings, then you can format it in whatever format you like. However, if you turn it into a string, you won't be able to interact with it like a datetime object and won't be able to use any of the datetime functionality.

Comment: Very True!! So if you ever feels like that I need to convert it back to DateTime. You can do ```pd.DatetimeIndex```